# WCF RIA Services Domain Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight Navigation Application . 
In this solution , I have added a WCF RIA Services Class Library.
Then I have added ADO.NET Entity Data Model object and then a Domain Service Class object , and I have a lot of generated methods which query my DB. In my silverlight app I can use all the methods that were generated and I get data from the DB but when I add my method , I don't see it in the intellisens when I want to use it. What could be my problem?
thanks.

this is my method -

```
public IQueryable<Professions> GetProffessionsStartsWith(string startsWith)
    {
        IQueryable<Profissions> professions = (from p in ObjectContext.Professions where p.Name.StartsWith(startsWith) select p);
        return profissions;
    }
```

Comment: Can i see your methods ?

Comment: @Masoomian I have added my method to the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must put [Query] before methods that return IQueryable result

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<Professions> GetProffessionsStartsWith(string startsWith)
{        
 IQueryable<Profissions> professions = (from p in ObjectContext.Professions where p.Name.StartsWith(startsWith) select p);      
   return profissions;    
 }
```